# Styling divs that have dynamic names

Tags: css

My code creates CSS divs with dynamic names

```
i.e.
  cke_record_body_19
  cke_record_body_54
```

Is it possible to style all divs that contain the string **cke_record_body_** in their name using CSS?

Comment: And it's impossible to give them all a CSS class, because...?

Comment: class seems more logical then ID, to do styling etc on them.

what do you want to achieve

Comment: The div names are created automatically by ckEditor so I can't add class names to them, and I'm using a rails plugin called active_scaffold for my admin pages which means it's a little harder to style the form - :-)

Comment: maybe you should tweak ckeditor a little to fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure:

$("[id^=cke_record_body]*").something()

Comment: I don't think he's using jQuery

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't even thought of using JS for this, and since I have prototype installed, I will just use this approach - thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Can you just have your code give these divs a class="cke_record_body" attribute? Then you can just apply a style to them however you want and ignore the ids.

If you really have to this should work:

```
div[id*="cke_record_body_"] {

}
```

Keep in mind I believe this is CSS3 so I have no idea what current support is, but really this is the only way to do it in straight CSS without other libraries. If you are using jQuery or something see Nealv's answer.

Comment: Its not going to work in much, but if he's talking straight CSS there isn't really away unless he adds class attributes or a jQuery like library.

Comment: thanks a lot - this technique actually works fine - i am however, going to use the JS approach suggested by Nealv as my admin pages already rely heavily on prototypejs - thanks again as this technique will possibly be of use to me in other projects

Answer (score 2):

The best cross browser solution is to style them by adding a class to each `div`.

Comment: yeah, if I hack around with the code for ckEditor, I'm sure I could apply a classname - if it wasn't for the fact that both Nealv and jwsample's suggestions work, then I'd probably do just that :)  thanks